How to show debug information during code execution on Windows and Linux?
The Delphi function OutputDebugString() is only for Windows. Is there a version supporting Linux?
uses
  Winapi.Windows;

...

var 
  DebugMsg : string;
begin 
  OutputDebugString('report a status .... ');

  DebugMsg := 'report a status ....';
  OutputDebugString(PChar(DebugMsg));


That is a Windows API function, not a Delphi function.

There is no equivalent of OutputDebugString() on Linux. You can either write to stdout/stderr normally, or use a custom/3rdparty logging solution.

@DelphiCoder I use QuickLogger under Windows (GetIt can pull it in together with QuickLib), maybe it works on Linux as well. It's nice code, we extended it to log to TCP as well.

As Remy Lebeau mentioned in a comment,

There is no equivalent of OutputDebugString() on Linux. You can either write to stdout/stderr normally, or use a custom/3rdparty logging solution.

Recommendations for such a third-party solution are off-topic here.
